# Constructor with setter/getter returns string

Tags: javascript

I just received a quick JS test to complete from my employer, and I got lost. On the last question he asked me to do the following:

> Using JavaScript, implement a 'chart' function according to the
>   example:
>
> Note: '===' is used below to communicate the expected output.

```
var myBarChart = chart(); 
myBarChart.type() === 'line';
myBarChart.type('bar'); 
myBarChart.type() === 'bar'; 
myBarChart() === "Here's your bar chart!";

var myScatterChart = chart().type('scatter'); 
myScatterChart() === "Here's your scatter chart!";
```

I said I can't do it, but is it invalid, or I just lost my mind completely? It isn't a constructor, as it's not having new parameter. And also it wouldn't return a string, if that would accept any Setters. Or am I wrong?

Please, answer my question, as I'm feeling dumb now.

Comment: So what exactly is your question? Just fulfill the requirements line by line, one at a time. 1st line - you create an empty function named `chart`. Done. 2nd - it returns an object with a property named `type` that is a function that returns a `line` string. Done. Etc.

Comment: Nothing special about it, simple object usage. But I see why you got puzzled `myBarChart()` how is it possible? Well, functions are objects too.

Comment: could you guys write down this example for me, please? As an answer. I will mark it as completed

Comment: "could you guys write down this example for me, please?" --- it would teach you nothing.

Comment: @zerkms - I disagree.  It taught me a *lot* to see the answers provided, and I think I knew enough that I could have answered the question...

Comment: @cale_b by looking how people solve your tasks you only learn to mimic what they do, not how to solve arbitrary unknown problems. The real issue here is that the OP cannot decompose the problem. Or does not know JS basics. Either is not to be solved with "let's see how I would solve it".

Comment: @zerkms - Again, I disagree.  Different people learn differently, and I learned a lot from this.  While granted the OP could / should have at least shown what they tried - and maybe I learned a lot because I already have a decent handle on js - but some people learn great from "deconstructing" something that is already built.  I know it's been a major part of my learning how to code....

Comment: `the OP could / should have at least shown what they tried` - well, OP said `I said I can't do it` and the question as asked goes on about constructors and setters and getters ... so, clearly OP could not show any attempt because OP was not even in the right ballpark :p

Comment: @JaromandaX so if the OP does not know how to define a function (step 1), then they must learn at least very basics of JS first, not ask how to complete the whole task.

Comment: @zerkms - I don't disagree with you

Comment: @JaromandaX and I don't argue with you ;-)

Comment: @zerkms I do agree with you overall. I always firstly try to solve the problem myself. But I just needed someone to explain it to me more clearly, and by description of  people below, I finally understood what I was doing wrong. Thank you alot all of you!

Comment: I like these discussions about how OP must provide his attempts, must learn something. Come on, guys :) Do you really care if OP learns something or just copies? I like question - I answer, because it's interesting for me. If OP can benefit from it - awesome! If not, well it's his life. They ask for help, I can help and have fun - great. It's not important if they don't make any other attempt other then posting question. Question is already effort for some people.

Comment: @dsfq "Do you really care if OP learns something or just copies?" --- If I did not - I would post an answer first and get my couple upvotes (and maybe a checkmark). "They ask for help, I can help" --- there is difference, in a lot of cases people don't realise they ask for wrong things. Feeding them with one-time answers is bad for everyone.

Comment: @zerkms Well, people have different methods: you think you help by not answering, some people do answer and think they help like this. And some people answer but don't help.

Comment: I really did put effort, next time I'll provide link to jsfiddle for you to see!

Comment: @dfsq make a calendar reminder to check in half a year latest OP's questions :-)

Comment: @zerkms You think they will improve? Maybe, very likely. Still doesn't prove anything.

Comment: guys, for what kind of purpose this piece of code could be potentially used for? I don't mean dummy examples, but real usage. That's what I'm learning like.

Comment: @patrykcieszkowski nothing. It's purely synthetic and you should never ever write anything like that for production.

Comment: @zerkms good, thanks for your reply

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a number of concepts at play here.

First of all, you can have a function that returns another function:

```
 function chart() {
      var fn = function() {
          console.log('You are calling the anonymous function!')
      };

      return fn;
 }

 let myBarChart = chart();
 myBarChart();
```

Secondly, you can attach additional fields to functions. (If you come from a C# or Java background that might feel wrong, but you can do this in Javascript).

```
 function chart() {
      var fn = function() {
          console.log('You are calling the anonymous function!')
      };

      // Attaching a new field
      fn.type = function() {
          console.log('Now you are calling the type function!');
      }
      return fn;
 }

 let myBarChart = chart();
 myBarChart.type();
```

Thirdly, there's a [pattern](https://martinfowler.com/bliki/OverloadedGetterSetter.html) in javascript where you use the same function as a getter or setter. It's discussed on the [Software Engineering Stackexchange site](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/109943/combining-getters-and-setters).

```
function chart() {
     var typeValue = 'line';

     var fn = function() {
         return (typeValue === 'line' ? "Here's your line chart!" : "Here's your bar chart!");
     };


     fn.type = function(value) {
          if(typeof(value) !== 'undefined') {
             typeValue = value;
             return fn;
          } else {
             return typeValue;
          }
     };

     return fn;
}

let myChart = chart();
myChart.type() === 'line';
myChart() === "Here's your line chart!";
let setterReturnValue = myChart.type('bar');
setterReturnValue === myChart;
myChart() === "Here's your bar chart!";
```

The example he provided demonstrates what you can do with these three concepts.

Comment: Thank you for your effort in explaining this to me. That helps alot!

Answer (score 3):

It's definitely possible. The first line `var myBarChart = chart();` tells you that `chart` is a function, so you have:

```
function chart ( ) {

}
```

The next line `myBarChart.type()` tells you that the value returned by `chart()` is an object with a `type` property that is itself a function that returns `'line'`. So now you have:

```
function chart ( ) {
    return {
        type: function ( ) {
            return 'line';
        }
    }
}
```

The next line `myBarChart.type('bar');` doesn't tell you anything on its own, but the line after that tells us that subsequent calls to `.type()` should return the new type, so `.type()` is acting as both a setter and getter (analogous to [jQuery's val](http://api.jquery.com/val/), for example). So now you have something like:

```
function chart ( ) {
    var storedType = 'line';
    return {
        type: function ( newType ) {
            if ( newType )
                storedType = newType;
            else
                return storedType;
        }
    }
}
```

The next line `myBarChart()` tells us that the return value of `chart` actually needed to be a function, not a plain object. That function needs to return `'Here\'s your ' + storedType + ' chart!'` and it needs to have the `type` property that our object had before. The easiest way to add a property to a function is to store that function in a variable and then add the property. So the result is:

```
function chart ( ) {
    var storedType = 'line';
    var func = function ( ) {
        return 'Here\'s your ' + storedType + ' chart!';
    };
    func.type = function ( newType ) {
        if ( newType )
            storedType = newType;
        else
            return storedType;
    }
    return func;
}
```

The next two line `var myScatterChart = chart().type('scatter');` tells you that when `.type` is called with an argument, it should return the same function as was returned by calling `chart()`. That can be done by either returning `func` or `this` to complete the answer:

```
function chart ( ) {
    var storedType = 'line';
    var func = function ( ) {
        return 'Here\'s your ' + storedType + ' chart!';
    };
    func.type = function ( newType ) {
        if ( newType ) {
            storedType = newType;
            return func;
        } else
            return storedType;
    }
    return func;
}
```

Comment: down to 3th code sample was where I was for a while, but as you noticed - it didn't make sense for me , so that'd be an object. But you're right, as function is an object in JS, i completely ignored that. Even though I had it in back of my head. I knew this day isn't my day. Thank you alot for your effort!

Comment: @JanKulczyk You're welcome. I hope the way I broke it down was helpful for you.

Answer (score 1):

You need to know that functions are first class objects. It means that like any other normal object it can have properties. Knowing that you could implement this function something like this. Here is one possible solution:

```
function chart () {
  const obj = () => `Here's your ${obj.type()} chart!`
  let __type = 'line'

  obj.type = type => {
    if (type) {
      __type = type
      return obj
    }
    return __type
  }
  return obj
}
```

1. `var myBarChart = chart()` - `chart` must return new function.
2. `myBarChart.type() === 'line'` - returned function must have `type` property which is another function, which returns some sort of type (`line` or `chart`).
3. `myBarChart.type('bar')` - when used as a setter, set `__type` to new value. Let's keep it as local variable `__type`.
4. `chart` returns a function which when called returns a string with type information.

Comment: You may improve it if use a local variable for `type` and not spoil the returned object.

Comment: to be accurate, it's line 1 **and 5** combined that indicate `chart()` needs to return a function. line 1 by itself does not indicate this :p

Comment: @JaromandaX to be even more accurate, line 1 does not indicate a function needs to return anything at all ;-P

Comment: Yes, you are right, 1 and 5 indicate, but it's not important :)

Comment: I did knew function is treated like a function, but apparently I tried to do it other way round. What an embarrassment. Thanks!.